# Make Unweighted Clothing follow Rig in Pose Mode

Tags: armature, physics, weight-painting, cloth-simulation, pose-mode

I have a character modeled and rigged with clothing, and I want to maker her sit in pose mode.

[image]

The vest is weight painted so that the part of the vest around the shoulders and upper back follows the armature. Further, the entire vest *is* parented to the armature. However, the lower part of the vest is weighted painted zero for all bones, and instead a cloth modifier controls the movement of the hanging part.

This is all fine and dandy when adjusting the pose of Sara while running the cloth simulation. However, when I want to set an initial pose before running the simulation, I get the following ugliness:

[image]

The top portion of the vest moves just fine with the rig. But the lower portion of the vest stays completely static because all the weight painting values on that part of the vest are zero.

If I run the simulation, the fabric will eventually settle down. However, because it's so stretched out to begin with, often the fabric will settle down in a messy, tangled mess, and never in the correct starting position.

I am wondering how I would go about setting up the initial frame so that the lower part of the vest is more aligned with the position you would expect it to be in a starting frame. Do I have to manually adjust the unweighted vertices? That sounds clumsy.

Also, please ignore the weirdness of the skirt in the second image. The issue with the skirt is just because of weight painting issues there as well, but none of the vertices on the skirt should be weight painted zero, so it's just an issue of fixing the painting there.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Just weight the whole vest, and make sure your armature modifier is before your cloth modifier.  It will move appropriately on frame 1, before the cloth simulation has started.  After the cloth simulation starts, the cloth will override the armature.

Comment: Yeah... that fixed it. Should I move to delete this post? Or answer it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, figured it out. Like @Nathan said, I should have just weighted the entire vest and changed the order of the modifiers. My bad. Question Closed.